# How to decrypt data encrypted by openssl AES-256-GCM in python

Tags: python, encryption, openssl

So I have encrypted some text with the following linux commend:

```
echo abc >> in
openssl enc -aes-256-gcm -base64 -k aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa -iv 1234567890123456 -in in
```

And I have the following output:
`U2FsdGVkX18MpgFlt0vNFLXyrKI=`

I can decrypt the text with the following commend:

```
echo "U2FsdGVkX18MpgFlt0vNFLXyrKI=" > in
openssl enc -aes-256-gcm -base64 -k aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa -iv 1234567890123456 -in in -d
```

And I have the following output:
`abc`

What I would like to achieve is to decrypt the output `U2FsdGVkX18MpgF1t0vNFLXyrKI=` with python. But I have tried many example I can find and none of them works. I am completely clueless.

Below is what I have tried:

```
from Cryptodome.Cipher import AES
import base64

# Just To test out 
c = AES.new(b'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa',AES.MODE_GCM,b'1234567890123456')
enc = c.encrypt(b'abc')
print(enc)
# >> b'\xcaA\x8e'
c = AES.new(b'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa',AES.MODE_GCM,b'1234567890123456')
print(c.decrypt(enc))
# >> b'abc'

#Using the value from openssl
enc = base64.b64decode("U2FsdGVkX18MpgFlt0vNFLXyrKI=")
print(enc)
# >>b'Salted__\x0c\xa6\x01e\xb7K\xcd\x14\xb5\xf2\xac\xa2'

c = AES.new(b'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa',AES.MODE_GCM,b'1234567890123456')
print(c.decrypt(enc))
# >> b'\xf8B\x81\x98K\xcf\xebF\x92\x04{?v\xdb\xcbL\x8e\xab\x8f\xfa'
print(base64.b64encode(c.decrypt(enc)))
# >> b'l7aUC53L+qTiEzxWXziUEFckW/Y='
c = AES.new(base64.b64decode('aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'),AES.MODE_GCM,base64.b64decode('1234567890123456'))
#error....
print(c.decrypt(enc))
```

apparently the enc text by openssl is salted, i have no idea to handle that.

Comment: At least show what you tried and where failed!

Comment: Sure, I have updated my question

Comment: With `-k` a password is specified. Is this intended? If so, OpenSSL uses a key derivation function, which is missing in the posted Python code. If, however, a key is intended to be applied, use `-K`. Note that `-iv` and `-K` expect hex digits, see  https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/enc.html, which doesn't seem to be considered in either code.

Comment: The password salt is always eight bytes, just after `b'Salted__'`. So in this case the salt would be `b'\x0c\xa6\x01\x65\xb7\x4b\xcd\x14'`. However, the ciphertext has just **four bytes remaining** after that (which is the same length as your plaintext, `b'abc\n'`), which implies no MAC tag. Also, OpenSSL's documentation and mailing lists are _vociferous_ about the fact that they absolutely refuse to support authenticated modes with the `enc` utility lest users misuse the capability. Are you **sure** that's the command you ran, and not `…cbc` or `…ecb` or one of the other supported modes?

Comment: To be clear, I can't even get your test decryption command to work. What version of OpenSSL \([ever](https://mta.openssl.org/pipermail/openssl-users/2018-July/008309.html)\) supported that?